# Snapchat url scheme not working properly - camera opens but not profile

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I am trying this http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/snapchat and the app opens and shows the camera instead of showing me the profile.

Is there another URL scheme for snapchat?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works right now:  `https://snapchat.com/add/username`:

`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://snapchat.com/add/username")));`

Comment: This is not working for me, can anyone else confirm that this is still working?

Comment: no, Snapchat makes directly a redirection to the app store

Comment: @Jayz7522 I got the same result.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to open snapchat application just then use :

```
snapchat://
```

If you want to add any user to friend list you can use this :

```
snapchat://add/snapchatUsername
```

Answer (score 3):

I've spent a fair amount of time looking into this, and I don't think there's any information out there right now about app URLs that do anything in Snapchat except just open the app. The `?u=username` thing in the other answer and elsewhere on the Internet doesn't work (at least not for current versions of Snapchat).

Comment: This doesnt work now! Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35095091/416412)