# How do I share a link to Whatsapp on Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, share, dynamic-linking

I'm working on a cross-platform PLC project on Xamarin.Forms. Specifically on iOS and Android.

In one of the views I have 3 sharing buttons, one for Whatsapp, one for Snapchat and one for general sharing. The idea is that when the user taps on one of these he sends an invitation (a deep link) to his friends trough social media.

I've implemented some android-specific code to share a link trough Whatsapp or Snapchat when tapping those buttons, and to show the normal sharing screen to pick an app on the other share button. For this I just used `Intent.SetPackage` method to share on the specific apps.

On iOS however, even tho there's a code to open the general sharing screen, I couldn't find any code to send the link to Whatsapp or Snapchat specifically.

My question would be, is there a way to achieve this on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the end we didn't find what we where looking for, but we noticed apps usually just have a common share button on iOS, so we left only the normal sharing code in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This could maybe be a solution for WhatsApp, https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030

Snapchat: [Snapchat url scheme not working properly - camera opens but not profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632121/snapchat-url-scheme-not-working-properly-camera-opens-but-not-profile)

Comment: i don't think I was clear enough, what I need to send is a deep link, the idea is that the user clicks on share and sends to their friends a deep link with info about the app, we can do this for the share button, but the idea is that the Whatsapp and Snapchat buttons open directly those apps for sending the link to whoever the user wants to.